# --staging-table while loading data to sql server (sqoop)

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, apache-pig, sqoop

I am getting following error msg when I am trying to load data to sql server 2012 with sqoop.

(org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager) does not support staging of data for export. Please retry without specifying the --staging-table option

But the same code is working fine in mysql.

Is it something to do with the sql server compatibility with sqoop.

How to fix this issue

I am using following arg in sqoop export

```
String arguments[] = new String[] {
            "export",
            "--connect",
            configuration.get(PROPERTY_DBSTRING),
            "--username",
            configuration.get(PROPERTY_DBUSERNAME),
            "--password",
            configuration.get(PROPERTY_DBPASSWORD),
            "--verbose",
            "--table",
            tableName,
            "--staging-table",
            "TEMP_" + tableName,
            "--clear-staging-table",
            "--input-fields-terminated-by",
            configuration.get(PROPERTY_SQOOP_FIELD_SEPARATER),
            "--export-dir",
            configuration.get(PROPERTY_INPUT_DATADIRECTORY) + "/" + tableName };
           return Sqoop.runTool(arguments, configuration);
```

Comment: Staging is not supported in SQLServer

Comment: yeah that is why I created my own temp table for staging purpose